# how to multiply the time(hours and minutes) to the hourly rate in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, time

i have a textbox that have already time and i will multiply it to 85.23, but it gives some error in VB.net?

```
        Dim g As String
        Dim p As String
        Dim gp As Integer

        g = CStr(TextBox13.Text)
        p = CStr(85.23)
        gp = cstr(g * p)

        TextBox15.Text = gp
```

any one can help me to create daily salary calculation?
thanks in advance for your helps. :)

Comment: Why are you converting numbers to strings to do math on them?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to multiply two strings together.  Try parsing g and p as a decimals and you should be good to go.

Comment: Always use the `Decimal` type when working with money, not `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert TextBox13 to a DateTime variable, then use the DatePart function to get the number of hours, minutes, etc. so you can multiply by the salary.

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying strings. This operation is not allowed. To multiply numbers you must convert strings to numbers. For example, using decimals.

```
    Dim g As Decimal
    Dim p As Decimal
    Dim gp As Decimal

    g = Decimal.Parse(TextBox13.Text)
    p = 85.23D
    gp = g * p

    TextBox15.Text = gp.ToString()
```

You can use the number type you prefer: integers and Unsigned integers or long. 
Floating point number are supported as well.